# Java implementation of planarity testing/planar embedding

Tags: java, graph-layout, graph-drawing

Is there a free Java implementation of any of the major [planarity testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing) algorithms?  Boyer-Myrvold, de Fraysseix-Rosenstiehl, heck, even Hopcroft-Tarjan.  I've been reading the papers and they all seem fairly complex, and I'd rather skip all the work of implementing them myself if someone else has already done so.

Answer (score 3):

[JGraphEd](http://www.jharris.ca/JGraphEd/) has some planarity testing but I haven't used it.